# Module instance filename is null, but why?

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

I have this code which creates a Node.js module from memory:

```
function requireFromString(src, filename) {
  var Module = module.constructor;
  var m = new Module(filename);
  m._compile(src, filename);
  return m;
}

console.log(
  requireFromString(
    'module.exports = { test: 1}',
    '/some/file/path.js'
  )
);
```

when I run it I get this output:

```
Module {
  id: '/some/file/path.js',
  exports: { test: 1 },
  parent: undefined,
  filename: null,     // <<< humma?
  loaded: false,
  children: [] }
```

does anyone know why filename is null? seems funny that id is the filename, and filename is null. I am on Node.js version 10.

Comment: what are you trying to archive? you are not suppose to call a `_` prefixed method. Also the `_compile` method was changed since node v6 https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11461#issuecomment-280905949

Comment: nah my code looks fine according to this: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L678

Comment: I was just asking the question b/c I am curious, but ultimately I am just trying to load a module from memory instead of from disk. I want to know what filename to use when loading from memory.

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L616 well `filename` get assigned on `.load()`, but if you directly call `_compiled()` you would have skipped that step

Comment: ahh i see, will take a look at that tomorrow thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [Module constructor](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/33a25b29a4d654f5c2a5c74725862bccb2fcccfb/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L105), it actually does `this.filename = null`

The filename is later set in [Module.prototype._load](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/33a25b29a4d654f5c2a5c74725862bccb2fcccfb/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L524) which resolves the filename and calls [module.load](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/33a25b29a4d654f5c2a5c74725862bccb2fcccfb/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L612) to set the internal property `this.filename`.

In your case you are calling `_compile` directly without loading the file, so the `filename` property remains `null`.

This is just an overview, the internal logic of `require` is quite complex with a lot of caching and native function calls, so I don't think you should try to use the `filename` property in your code.

If you need to somehow use the file name, I would create a new property in your code, let's say `myfilename`, making sure it doesn't interfere with node's internal logic.